# PowerShell - Substring regex

Tags: powershell

I need to search a file for any string that contains the sub-strings "ME" and "SW", in this order, with any character (even non-alphanumerical), before, between and after them.

So far this line works for me:

```
*select-string -path "..path" -pattern ME*
```

But, when I try the regex `[.]*ME[.]*SW[.]*` it returns null.

Also, when using `[.]*ME[.]*` it works.

Comment: Have you tried quoting the pattern?

Comment: `[.]` will match a literal `.`, remove the brackets in order for it to match any character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try this....

```
ME.*SW
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Could you explain the difference, I'm a little confused.

Comment: The dot symbol is a metacharacter which matches any character excluding line break characters.
But if you use it inside brackets it matches only a dot character.

For example :

 AA[.]

matches the string "AA.", but not the string "AAA" and

 AA.

matches the string "AA." and also the string "AAA"

Hope it helps

Comment: The `.*` before and after `ME.*SW` are  redundant.